# C and libappindicator - Creating multiple indicators

Tags: c, gtk, appindicator

I'm programming a simple indicator that is supposed to show an icon for each CPU Core in the Unity panel, that will change color depending on the temperature range.

That would require me to have more than one AppIndicator on the same program, since I think there's no way to have one AppIndicator with multiple icons or use a gtk_container to hold those and append it to the AppIndicator. I'm actually trying to use 1 AppIndicator for the menu (with the "Quit" option) and 1 AppIndicator for each CPU Core.

The program had no Gtk warnings with just one AppIndicator (the main one), but after I added the code for creating the other 2 AppIndicators for each CPU Core (both with different unique id's) Gtk started throwing some warnings and critical messages. The indicators show up in the panel just like they are supposed to, but I don't want to simply ignore those messages, as they could be hiding some real issues under the curtains.

Checking the code, the only thing I think could be triggering those warnings and critical messages is `app_indicator_new()` being called more than once, I actually removed all the menu and menu_item's creation routines for those extra indicators, leaving only the `app_indicator_new()` call and I still get those messages (one for each extra `app_indicator_new()` call after the first):

```
(process:8040): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(process:8040): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(process:8040): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

When I add the code with the menu being created and associated with the extra AppIndicator's some extra errors show up:

```
(process:8681): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(process:8681): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(process:8681): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(process:8681): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(process:8681): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(process:8681): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(process:8681): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(process:8681): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(process:8681): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(process:8681): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(process:8681): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(process:8681): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(process:8681): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(process:8681): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(process:8681): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(process:8681): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(process:8681): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(process:8681): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(process:8681): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(process:8681): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(TempI:8681): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window

(TempI:8681): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(TempI:8681): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(TempI:8681): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(TempI:8681): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(TempI:8681): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window

(TempI:8681): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(TempI:8681): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(TempI:8681): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(TempI:8681): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

I can post the code of the program if necessary, just didn't do it because it would make the question even larger. That's the block where I'm creating the extra AppIndicators though:

```
for(int i=0; i<TempI_Main.Cores_Counter; i++){
    TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root=gtk_menu_new();

    //The core name ("Core " + number)
    char IndicatorName[TEMPI_MAX_CHARS];
    snprintf(IndicatorName, TEMPI_MAX_CHARS,"TempI_Core %u",i);

    TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root_Description=gtk_menu_item_new_with_label(IndicatorName);
    gtk_menu_append(GTK_MENU(TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root),TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root_Description);
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(GTK_WIDGET(TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root_Description),FALSE);
    gtk_widget_show(TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root_Description);

    TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Indicator=app_indicator_new(IndicatorName,"indicator-messages",APP_INDICATOR_CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS);
    app_indicator_set_status(TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Indicator, APP_INDICATOR_STATUS_ACTIVE);
    //Need to set icon
    //Need to set attention icon

    app_indicator_set_menu(TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Indicator,GTK_MENU(TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root));
}
```

Any clues what could be the cause? **Are multiple AppIndicators per program not supported**?

**EDIT:**

Corrected code after @Jean-François Fabre answer.

```
for(int i=0; i<TempI_Main.Cores_Counter; i++){
    TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root=gtk_menu_new();

    //The core name ("Core " + number)
    char IndicatorName[TEMPI_MAX_CHARS];
    //MAX_CHARS - 6 ("Core "+'\0') is the limit for appending
    snprintf(IndicatorName, TEMPI_MAX_CHARS,"TempI_Core %u",i);

    TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Indicator_Name=strdup(IndicatorName);

    TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root_Description=gtk_menu_item_new_with_label(TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Indicator_Name);
    gtk_menu_append(GTK_MENU(TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root),TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root_Description);
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(GTK_WIDGET(TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root_Description),FALSE);
    gtk_widget_show(TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root_Description);

    TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Indicator=app_indicator_new(TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Indicator_Name,"indicator-messages",APP_INDICATOR_CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS);
    app_indicator_set_status(TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Indicator, APP_INDICATOR_STATUS_ACTIVE);
    //Need to set icon
    //Need to set attention icon

    app_indicator_set_menu(TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Indicator,GTK_MENU(TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root));
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Code for creating a single Core indicator explicitely. Still throwing warnings and critical messages:

```
TempI_Main.Core[0].Gtk_Menu_Root=gtk_menu_new();

TempI_Main.Core[0].Gtk_Menu_Root_Description=gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Core1");
gtk_menu_append(GTK_MENU(TempI_Main.Core[0].Gtk_Menu_Root),TempI_Main.Core[0].Gtk_Menu_Root_Description);
gtk_widget_set_sensitive(GTK_WIDGET(TempI_Main.Core[0].Gtk_Menu_Root_Description),FALSE);
gtk_widget_show(TempI_Main.Core[0].Gtk_Menu_Root_Description);

TempI_Main.Core[0].Gtk_Indicator=app_indicator_new("Core1","indicator-messages",APP_INDICATOR_CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS);
app_indicator_set_status(TempI_Main.Core[0].Gtk_Indicator, APP_INDICATOR_STATUS_ACTIVE);
//Need to set icon
//Need to set attention icon

app_indicator_set_menu(TempI_Main.Core[0].Gtk_Indicator,GTK_MENU(TempI_Main.Core[0].Gtk_Menu_Root));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root of the issue and it's embarassing to say, but I just misplaced the function that created the AppIndicator. **It was being called before** `gtk_init()` so that's where all those errors were coming from. First I had:

```
TempI_Set_Core_Indicator();

//Starts gtk
gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

TempI_Set_Main_Indicator();
```

and simply replacing it by:

```
//Starts gtk
gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

TempI_Set_Main_Indicator();
TempI_Set_Core_Indicator();
```

was enough to solve the problem. I was focusing so much on the function itself that I didn't stop to look where it was being called.

Answer (score 1):

That in a loop is just bad:

```
char IndicatorName[TEMPI_MAX_CHARS];
snprintf(IndicatorName, TEMPI_MAX_CHARS,"TempI_Core %u",i);
TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root_Description=gtk_menu_item_new_with_label(IndicatorName);
...
TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Indicator=app_indicator_new(IndicatorName, ...
```

You are declaring `IndicatorName` as an auto variable in the loop but pass it to `gtk_menu_item_new_with_label` which expects a `const char *`, means: it will just store the address of the string.

Not only the memory will be reused for further iterations and all menus will have the same indicator name within the loop, but exiting the loop the memory will be allocated to some other variable and the names will be trashed => undefined behaviour

You should make *a copy* of the string like this:

```
TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Menu_Root_Description=gtk_menu_item_new_with_label(strdup(IndicatorName));
```

(of course a better way would be to store the copied string to be able to deallocate them if needed)

Comment: Man, what have I done?!? :o Thanks for pointing that out!! I created an extra field for the name "TempI_Main.Core[i].Gtk_Indicator_Name" and used it instead. I'm still getting the warnings and critical messages though. I'll post the new loop code in the question as an Edit!

Comment: Could the problem be that the heap is dynamic and the string could be changing position during the programs execution? The libappindicator would still have the old address and result in the same undefined behaviour? I'll try using string literals and see what the result is.

Comment: with strdup it should be OK. Are you sure that `TEMPI_MAX_CHARS` is big enough? I would reduce the loop to 1 iteration: easy to do, might shed some light...

Comment: TEMPI_MAX_CHARS is a macro for 4096. I tried making a single core indicator explicitely (all literal strings) and still had the warnings/critical messages. I'll post the code from this test in "Edit2:". Maybe this is some limitation on libappindicator in regard to the number of indicators? Maybe the `app_indicator_new()` runs some routine that isn't supposed to be ran twice?

Comment: could `app_indicator_new` return `NULL`? and don't you `show` your widget too soon? I would show it after everything is set.

Comment: libappindicator seems to lack a really descriptive documentation. On the source I found for it (http://libappindicator.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.2.91.1/app-indicator_8c_source.html) `app_indicator_new` actually does `g_object_new (APP_INDICATOR_TYPE,PROP_ID_S, id,PROP_CATEGORY_S, category_from_enum (category),PROP_ICON_NAME_S, icon_name,NULL);`. I used an "if-statement" to check if it was returning NULL and it wasn't. Also, changing the `gtk_widget_show()` to the end of the routine didn't make any difference :/

Comment: I'm not a Gtk expert not even close, so I cannot help further if it's not a C-related issue like the first one.

Comment: I appreciate your help! Thanks for the heads up on the `const char *` misuse, could have lead to other bugs quite hard to track! :)

Comment: I found what the issue was! It was in another part of the code, where I was calling this function that sets the AppIndicator. It was being called before initializing Gtk with `gtk_init()`. Thanks for taking the time to help man!